# Flutter + Firebase - Link Phone Number with Existing Account

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have implemented Email Authentication using Firebase in Flutter. I want to take the phone number from the user and verify it by sending an OTP to ensure it belongs to them and then link their phone number with the account they created earlier using email.

For this purpose I did the following:

```
verifyPhoneNumber() async {
    await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: '+92${widget.phoneNumber}',
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        await auth.currentUser.updatePhoneNumber(credential);
        // either this occurs or the user needs to manually enter the SMS code
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        print(e.message);
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int resendToken) {
        setState(() {
          _otpcode = verificationId;
        });
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
        setState(() {
          _otpcode = verificationId;
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

The above code sends the OTP to the number. Now when the user enters the received code into the TextField I want to verify that both match so I can proceed with updatePhoneNumber.

I am not sure how to implement the verification part. I have the following code and not sure how to output the errors if any or to confirm the verification did happen.

```
verifyPhoneCode(otp, code) async {
  final AuthCredential credential =
      PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId: otp, smsCode: code);
  await auth.currentUser.updatePhoneNumber(credential);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I have finally figured out the solution. In order to link phone number with an already existing account use .linkWithCredential

```
final AuthCredential credential =
    PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: _otpcode,
        smsCode: val,
    );
currentUser
    .linkWithCredential(credential);
```

I hope it helps anyone looking for a solution to a similar problem.

Comment: so u didn't use the  function (auth.verifyPhoneNumber) ?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to go through the official [firebase flutter docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone). There they explained all the steps involved during the phone authentication step in a well mannered way.

Moreover, here is the code snippet from official docs which refers to the phone verification steps.

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
  phoneNumber: '+44 7123 123 456',
  codeSent: (String verificationId, int resendToken) async {
    // Update the UI - wait for the user to enter the SMS code
    String smsCode = 'xxxx';

    // Create a PhoneAuthCredential with the code
    PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);

    // Sign the user in (or link) with the credential
    await auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
  },
);
```

Comment: Salman thank you for kind reply. I am not looking to authenticate using Phone Number. I just want to verify the OTP and link with the existing user credentials.

Comment: Okay my bad. May be I did not understand your question properly.