# Add phone number verification to a user already registered with email password in firebase, flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

In my app, there is a login screen, registration screen and a showProfile screen. I am registering user with email and password. In the registration screen there are fields contain Image, first name, last name , & phone no. I can add the user display name, image URL to the specific user by doing this-

```
UserCredential user = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
var newUser = user.user;
if (newUser != null) {
    Reference imgReference = firebaseStorage.ref().child('UserImages/$_email');
    UploadTask uploadTask = imgReference.putFile(imgFile);
    TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask;
    String url = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    if (url != null) {
       setState(() {
          imgUrl = url;
       });
    }
    await newUser.updatePhotoURL(imgUrl);
    await newUser.updateDisplayName(_firstName + ' ' + _lastName);
    await newUser.reload();
}
```

Now I want to add phone no with OTP verification to the user during registration process. . but I can't able to the the same thing for phone no without creating another user account with phone no.

So that after successful login, in my showProfile screen I can parse user phone no. by **user.phoneNumber** to the screen just like I can do this for **user.displayName** & **user.photoURL** without facing any problem.

**Is there any way to add phone no to the registered email account?** I searched about it but couldn't find anything to start with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verifying a phone number with Firebase Authentication is considered signing in with that provider. So instead of adding a phone number to existing sign-in, you're actually going to sign in the user with another provider and then linking that new provider to the existing user profile.

The steps are largely similar to [signing in with a phone number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth), but instead of calling `signInWithCredential(credential)` with the phone credentials, you call `linkWithCredential(credential)` on the current user as shown in the documentation on [account linking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking).

Above are links to the Android docs, as I feel those document this process clearest and the process is similar across platforms. For FlutterFire equivalents, see the docs for [phone auth](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone) and [account linking](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#linking-user-accounts).

Comment: Thanks. After reading the doc (https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone/) u gave, I progressed a bit.

Answer (score 2):

So after a long search, find & try solutions, I finally was able to solve my problem. Added a phone number using firebase OTP verification to a already registered email-pass account. Thankfully this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66873965/15450771) worked for me just perfectly fine. Here's the code:

```
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final userInfo = _auth.currentUser;    

Future<void> phoneVerification() async {
        await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: _mobile,
          verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {
            /// This is the main important line to link
            await userInfo.linkWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
            // Not nessecary
            /* User? refreshedUser = await refreshUser(userInfo);
            if (refreshedUser != null) {
              setState(() {
                userInfo = refreshedUser;
              });
            } */
          },
          verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
           // Handle error
            print(e);
          },
          codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
            // write the code to handle the OTP code sent for manual verification in case autoverify doesn't work
          },
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
            // Do Something for SMS request timeout
          },
        );
      }
```

Comment: i'm getting error "User has already been linked to the given provider.", how did u resolve this?