# Add a phone number to a user that already sign up in firebase auth via email

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm a beginner to Flutter and Firebase I'm still referring to tutorials so bear with me on that. Currently, I've done so far with a sign-up process with an email with Firebase authentication. Those data are then added to Firestore as well ('email' is added at first, but later 'name'....) But after that screen, I'm going to add the user's phone number as well. Cool, I can push it to Firestore. But here comes the problem. Before that, I need to add phone otp auth. So how can I do it?

Also if this is a duplicate, feel free to add it here. Because I didn't find an answer to this.

I know that Firebase has phone auth, but then it creates another user, plus logged in with that user. I don't mind it but those needed to be at least merged. I don't mind going for this phone otp with a different provider and not only Firebase. And I would appreciate it if those are going with at least a basic free plan as I'm making this for a university project. ( I know then it's test numbers but that would help me as well )

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70535023/add-phone-number-verification-to-a-user-already-registered-with-email-password-i?rq=2

Answer (score 1):

> But after that screen, I'm going to add the user's phone number as well. Cool, I can push it to Firestore.

If you ask your users for the phone number, then you can simply update the user documents in Firestore. However, that doesn't mean that the phone number is also updated in the Firebase Authentication. So when it comes to users, Firestore and Firebase Authentication are not related in any way. If you need to have the phone number in the Firebase user object, then you to perform an update. So you need to call [User#updatePhoneNumber()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/updatePhoneNumber.html) and pass a [PhoneAuthCredential](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/PhoneAuthCredential-class.html) object as an argument. Since you're using Firebase sign in with the email and password, and not sign in with the phone number, you cannot simply get the credentials. However, you can verify the phone number first by calling [FirebaseAuth#verifyPhoneNumber()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/verifyPhoneNumber.html) and then perform the update. As soon as the verification is complete, you can get the credentials and perform the phone number update. In code, it should look like this:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        timeout: const Duration(minutes: 2),
        verificationCompleted: (credential) async {
          await (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).updatePhoneNumber(credential);
        },
        verificationFailed: null,
        codeSent: (verificationId, [forceResendingToken]) async {
          String smsCode;
          //Get the SMS code from the user
          final AuthCredential credential =
            PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);
          await (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).updatePhoneNumber(credential);
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: null);
```

It's not tested, but these are the operations.

Comment: Hey Kavishika. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?